# Criar "borda" em div que não passe pelo texto

Tags: html, css

Coloquei borda em aspa, pois não sei se é realmente borda o nome disso.

Eu gostaria de fazer com que isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fique dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso com a borda passando pelo texto, sem ficar por cima.

Como posso fazer isso utilizando css?

HTML:

```
<div class="divICMS"><h6>ICMS</h6>
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FederacaoViewModel>()
        .ID("formularioCadastro2")
                            .ShowValidationSummary(false)
                            .Items(items =>
                            {
                                items.AddGroup()
                                    .Items(groupItems =>
                                    {
                                groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.UF_AliqInterEstadual).CssClass("fedEstadual")
                                .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("70px").ID("fedEstadual"));
                                groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.UF_AliqInterna).CssClass("fedInterna")
                                .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("70px").ID("fedInterna"));
                                groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.UF_AliqFCP).CssClass("fedFCP")
                                .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("70px").ID("fedFCP"));
                            });
                                items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.UF_CalcularFCP).CssClass("fedCalFCP")
                                .Label(l => l.Visible(false))
                                .Editor(editor => editor.CheckBox().Text("Calcular Fundo de Combate à Pobreza"));
    })
    .FormData(Model)
            )

                </div >
```

CSS:

```
.divICMS
{
border: solid 0.01em;
padding: 6px;
height: 175px;
width: 335px;
position: absolute;
top: 130px;
text-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `fieldset` e `legend` e definir a borda normalmente, como no exemplo abaixo, usei o `padding` só para ficar mais "bonitinho".

```css
.conteudo{
  padding: 20px;
}
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Lorem Ipsum</legend>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html)